# Getting value from date picker issue

Tags: android, simpledateformat, android-datepicker

Im getting 3914-01-06 as an output when the datepicker selected value input
        is 2014-01-06

```
        int   day  = view.getDayOfMonth();
        int   month= view.getMonth();
        int   year = view.getYear();

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String formatedDate = sdf.format(new Date(year, month, day));
        Log.d("test", "" + formatedDate);//Here i'am retrieving 3914 instead 2014
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date()), `Date()`'s first argument is "the year minus 1900". That is why you get 3914 (=2014+1900). As the documentation also states, use `Calendar` or `GregorianCalendar` instead of `Date`.

Comment: Could you provide me some sample please?

Comment: if you want to continue to use `Date` just subtract the 1900 from your `year` variable: `int year = view.getYear() - 1900;`

Answer (score 0):

you better work with calendar, here's a simple example :

```
   public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    int [] tabd=new int[3];
tabd[0]=day;
    tabd[1]=month+1;
    tabd[2]=year;
    Button b1=(Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.yourButton);
    String d=tabd[0]+"-"+tabd[1]+"-"+tabd[2];
// d is your string that contain the date now you can do whatever you want with it
```

}

Comment: How do you get that string in a different class to use for something else. When i try to setText() all it does is set the text to the selected date. It doesn't allow me to store that data into a string to use elsewhere.